# Facebook sdk not working in tablet (Android) it work fine in phone

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

In my application i am using Facebook SDK for login in to application. It will work fine without any error in phone but if i am test my in tablet it  authorised user and generate the access token also but not fetch the user data. i am follow this link for this code http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/08/facebook-integration-with-android-app.html

i am sharing my imported code part

```
 /**
     * Function to login into facebook
     * */

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void loginToFacebook() {

        String access_token = obj_pref.get_access_token();
        long expires = obj_pref.get_access_expires();

        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
            Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "publish_stream",
                    "user_birthday" }, new DialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // Function to handle cancel event
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // Function to handle complete event
                    // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token

                    obj_pref.set_access_token(facebook.getAccessToken());

                    obj_pref.set_access_expires(facebook.getAccessExpires());
                    getProfileInformation();

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError error) {
                    // Function to handle error
                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                    // Function to handle Facebook errors
                }
            });
        } else if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {

            getProfileInformation();

        }
    }

    /**
     * Get Profile information by making request to Facebook Graph API
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void getProfileInformation() {
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Profile", response);
                String json = response;
                try {
                    // Facebook Profile JSON data
                    JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                    obj_pref.set_user_id(profile.getString("email"));

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            new send_fb_data().execute();
                     // upload user data to my database server
                        }

                    });

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });
```

can any body help me out for this issue even in tablet it will not give any error ...

Comment: Try to clean Application data and facebook app data in your tablet settings and try again.

Comment: already try but not working @Govtart

Comment: Ok and what Android OS version you tablet and phone have ? I recommended you to use facebook guild for implementing facebook login feature, this work perfect - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: both are working on same version  4.4.2